# Сохранить данные всех виджетов в текстовый документ или pdf

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qlabel, qlineedit

Небольшое приложение, которое должно сохранять информацию с виджетов в текстовый документ или .pdf.

На форме есть `QLabel`, `QLineEdit`, `QTableWidget`.

Как сохранить все данные с формы?

**form.py**

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit, QGridLayout, QMessageBox, QMenuBar,
                             QAction, qApp, )
import design_second_form22
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class LoginForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Login Form")
        self.resize(500,120)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        label_name = QLabel('<font size="4"> Username </font>')
        self.lineEdit_username = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_username.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your username')
        layout.addWidget(label_name,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_username,0,1)


        label_password = QLabel('<font size="4"> Password </font>')
        self.lineEdit_password = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_password.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your password')
        layout.addWidget(label_password,1,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_password,1,1)

        button_login = QPushButton("Login")
        button_login.clicked.connect(self.check_password)
        layout.addWidget(button_login,2,0,1,2)
        layout.setRowMinimumHeight(2,75)

        self.setLayout(layout)



    def check_password(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        if self.lineEdit_username.text() == '' and self.lineEdit_password.text() == '':
            form.hide()
            window.show()

        else:
            msg.setText('Incorrect password or login')
            msg.exec_()

class SecondaryForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,design_second_form22.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Secondary Form")
        self.resize(600,600)
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        editAction = QAction('&New',self)
        editAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        editAction.triggered.connect(self.create_new_file)
        exitAction = QAction('&Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)
        menubar =  QMenuBar(self)
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(editAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def create_new_file(self):
        window.close()
        new_window.show()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = SecondaryForm()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = LoginForm()
    form.show()
    # window = ExampleApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    # #window.show()

    window = SecondaryForm()
    new_window = SecondaryForm()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пример, который у вас есть.

Answer (score 5):

Ваш пример воспроизвести не получилось, но как вариант, сохранение в текстовый файл можно сделать так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QLabel("Это Label") 

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()

        self.tablewidget = QTableWidget(3, 4)
        self.tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['V1','V2','V3','V4']) 

        self.button = QPushButton("Save")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onClickSave)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.tablewidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def onClickSave(self):
        with open('test_save.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as out_file:
            print(f"{self.label.text()}", file=out_file)
            print(f"{self.lineEdit.text()}", file=out_file)

            for row in range(self.tablewidget.rowCount()):
                for column in range(self.tablewidget.columnCount()):
                    item = self.tablewidget.item(row, column)
                    print(item.text() if item else "", end=', ', file=out_file) 
                print('', file=out_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("MainWindow Save")
    w.resize(470, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: @Nata, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте и примите ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)